# Websocket web client gets 1006 when connecting with wss

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, websocket

I have a websocket node.js server and successfully connected from ios, android. But, failed when connecting using rxjs/webSocket in angular web app, got 1006 back.

I then run websocket server locally, connect localhost:4200 angular web app with the server-> ws://localhost:3000/ws, it works fine. Why can not connect with wss one.

Server:

```js
const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const cors = require('cors');

app.use("/", express.static("public"));
var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
  credentials: true
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

const wsApp = expressWs(app, server).app;
wsApp.ws("/ws", handleSocketConnection);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server started on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Client:

```js
public initSocket(clientId): void {
    console.log('init socket');
    this.socket = webSocket(environment.webSocket);

    this.socket.next({ "channel": "login", "name": clientId });

}

public getMessage(): Observable<IWebsocketMessage> {
    return new Observable<IWebsocketMessage>(observer => {
        this.socket.subscribe((data: IWebsocketMessage) => {
            console.log('message received: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
            observer.next(data);
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });


    });
    //    return this.socket.asObservable();
}
```

Comment: Because `wss` is not `ws`; basically `wss` is WebSocket over HTTPS. It requires an encrypted connection, which is not provided by your server code. Typically, you'd run a reverse proxy like nginx in front of this server to add HTTPS encryption.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for the comments. I tried to deploy web client code to prod - https, the same error (so https calling wss). In the past, I could get very clear message regarding wss VS ws. For example, if connecting non-encrypted websocket server, both ios and android will throw error.  Any suggestion I can trouble shoot?

Comment: it turns out the aws load balancer has the default idle timeout of 60 seconds which applies to its connections, connection was getting terminated by the load balancer after 60 seconds of inactivity. The solution is to send at least 1 byte of data before each idle timeout period elapses.

Comment: @H_H, I post reactjs code in my answer, if you deploy socket to aws, default idle time is 60s, you just need to implement reconnect socket code when new message comes in

Answer (score 0):

```
//Below is reactjs code that is working for a chat message app

var socket = new WebSocket('wss://your_socket_url/ws');
 
useEffect(() => { 
    connect();
    return () => {
      disconnect();
    }

  }, []);
 

  function disconnect() {

    clearInterval(reconnectInterval);
    socket.close();
  }


  function connect() {

    socket.onopen = (event) => {

      clearInterval(reconnectInterval);

      socket.send(JSON.stringify({
        channel: 'login',
        name: getUserId(),
      }));

    };

    socket.onmessage = (event) => {
      const json = JSON.parse(event.data);
      //add your logic 
    };

    socket.onclose = (event) => {

      reconnectInterval = setInterval(
        () => {
          reconnect();
        },
        1000,
      )
      // console.log('Socket is closed. Reconnect will be attempted in 1 second.', event);

    };

    socket.onerror = (err) => {

      clearInterval(reconnectInterval);

      console.error('Socket encountered error: ', err, 'Closing socket');
      socket.close();
    };

    function reconnect() {

      if (socket.readyState != WebSocket.CONNECTING) {
        socket = new WebSocket('wss://your_socket_url/ws');
        connect();
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const cors = require('cors');

app.use("/", express.static("public"));
var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
  credentials: true
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

const wsApp = expressWs(app, server).app;
wsApp.ws("/ws", handleSocketConnection);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server started on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Diziturk.club